# message queue full error in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have coded to get the info from the user and send an email of clicking a button. The program is getting executed for a while and then the simulator is crashing showing error

"DE427"-Message queue full... Here's the code that i have done...

```
if(field==SendMail)
```

{

```
            Message m = new Message();
            Address a = null;

            try {

                a = new Address("user@xyz.com", "Rahul");

            } catch (AddressException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address[] addresses = {a};
            try {
                m.addRecipients(net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);
                m.setContent("Name:"+Name.getText().toString()+"\n"+ "Phone :"+Phone.getText().toString()+
                        "\n"+ "Date & Time:"+DateShow.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Make:"+Make.getText().toString()+
                        "\n"+"Model:"+Model.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Miles:"+Miles.getText().toString()+"\n");
                m.setSubject("Appointment Request (Via Blackberry app)");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));

        }
```

Can anyone tell me what the error is and how to rectify the problem....Plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with certain versions of Windows XP and the Blackberry simulator version. Check this link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Simulator-quot-device-Error-DE427-quot/m-p/556321

If you clean up the simulator (delete .dmp files from simulator directory) and restart the simulator it works fine